# update columns in a table based on row values from another table

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, case, case-when

I have a table TABLE1 with data in this format:

```
    id     text       pct
    --     ---      -----
    1        AA        5
    1        BB        3
    1        CC        16
    2        BB        7
    3        CC        13
```

And another table TABLE2:

```
    id     columnAA      columnBB     columnCC
    --     -------       -------      --------
    1        0             0             0
    2        0             0             0
    3        0             0             0
```

I would like to update columns in table2 so my result will look like:

```
    id     columnAA      columnBB     columnCC 
    --     -------       -------      -------- 
    1        5              3             16 
    2        0              7              0 
    3        0              0             13
```

I tried with this code but it's not really working. It only updates one column!

```
    update a
      set columnAA = case when b.text = 'AA' then b.pct else columnAA end
     ,set columnBB = case when b.text = 'BB' then b.pct else columnBB end
     ,set columnCC = case when b.text = 'CC' then b.pct else columnCC end
    from table2 a
    join table1 b
      on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: You need to either do a PIVOT or do sub-selects for each column in your update.    OR you could JOIN to table1 once for each column in table2.

Comment: Thx mate. Can you show me some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tab Allerman stated, You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE2
SET columnAA = (SELECT TABLE1.pct FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.text = 'AA'AND TABLE2.id = TABLE1.id),
columnBB  = (SELECT TABLE1.pct FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.text = 'BB'AND TABLE2.id = TABLE1.id),
columnCC  = (SELECT TABLE1.pct FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.text = 'CC'AND TABLE2.id = TABLE1.id)
```

edit:

In looking more closely at your code.  Remove the second and third 'Set' and it should work.  You do not need to proceed each with the word 'Set' only the first.

Comment: your code works but its very slow.. i removed set from my code but still doesn't work

Comment: Then You may want to try a PIVOT.  A quick search will bear many examples that can quickly be modified to do what you ask.